# An Unreal process has crashed in unreal engine 5 after pushing to GitHub, are there some good ways to solve it?

Tags: unreal-engine5

The following is the error:

LoginId:a005eafa4b272e7e8ecde298de7eed2c

EpicAccountId:052bdbf235cc467b80515711fbb0e46f Assertion failed: !bInstancedStereoEnabled || (bInstancedMultiViewportEnabled || bMobileMultiViewFallback) [File:D:\build++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\RenderCore\Private\StereoRenderUtils.cpp] [Line: 125] If ISR is enabled, we need either multi-viewport (since we no longer support clip-distance method) or MMV fallback (which uses vertex layer). UnrealEditor_RenderCore

UnrealEditor_RenderCore

UnrealEditor_Engine

UnrealEditor_Engine

UnrealEditor_Engine

UnrealEditor

UnrealEditor

UnrealEditor

UnrealEditor

UnrealEditor

UnrealEditor

kernel32

ntdll

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix to this issue [in the Unreal Engine forums](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/unreal-engine-5-1-vr-project-crashes-while-being-creates/718702/9):

In the "DefaultEngine.ini" file you need to set the parameter vr.InstancedStereo to False:

```
vr.InstancedStereo=False
```